# Построение предложения с деепричастным в одном виде

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот

Подскажите, как перестроить предложение с деепричастным оборотом. В нем деепричастие стоит в форме совершенного вида, а глагол-сказуемое-несовершенного вида.

> Посвятив себя педагогической деятельности, Елена Ивановна всегда чувствовала высокую ответственность за свой выбор.

Может быть, почувствовала, но как-то некорректно.

Answer (score 2):

**Посвятив себя педагогической деятельности, Елена Ивановна всегда чувствовала большую ответственность  профессии учителя.**

1) Деепричастие сов. вида обозначает законченность предыдущего действия, далее следует глагол несовершенного вида.

2) Избыток слов в высоким и абстрактным значением (высокий, выбор) в одном предложении нежелателен.

Примеры:

В этом и заключается и честность, и **ответственность профессии**. [Вячеслав Суриков, Андрей Толстой. Война и живопись // «Эксперт», 2014]

«Моя задача ― объяснить вам, дать почувствовать всю **ответственность профессии “актер”**. [Т. В. Доронина. Дневник актрисы (1984)]

Comment: Но деепричастие сов вида должно указывать на действие,предшествующее действию,выраженному глаголом-сказуемым. Мне кажется, что глагол-сказуемое тоже нужно поставить в форму сов. вида - почувствовала?

Comment: Она посвятила себя педагогической деятельности, когда выбрала профессию учителя (поступила в институт, получила диплом). Или когда?

Comment: Я думаю так: она почувствовала высокую ответственность за свой выбор, когда посвятила себя пед.деятельности. Или нет?

Comment: Как же мне исправить?

Comment: Я думаю, что исправлять ничего не надо. Человек выбрал профессию учителя, занимался всю жизнь педагогической деятельностью  и ВСЕГДА при этом чувствовал большую ответственность этой профессии.